# Pin to/Unpin from Taskbar and Start Menu

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I need to provide “Pin to Taskbar”, “Pin to Start Menu”, “Unpin from Taskbar” and “Unpin from Start Menu” functionality in my application (developed in .Net framework 3.5). Currently I have achieved the functionality using the code snippet below:

```
Dim verbs As FolderItemVerbs = link.Verbs()
For i As Integer = 0 To verbs.Count - 1
  Dim verb As FolderItemVerb = verbs.Item(i)
  Dim verbName As String = verb.Name.Replace("&", String.Empty)
  If (verbName.Equals("pin to taskbar")) Or (verbName.Equals("unpin from taskbar")) Then
  ‘If (verbName.Equals("Pin to Start Menu")) Or (verbName.Equals("Unpin from Start Menu")) Then
    verb.DoIt()
  End If
Next
```

The code is working fine, but in my case my application is widely distributed all over the world so running the application with different locale setting (different languages) is very common. The above code has this limitation that it would not work for all different languages (e.g. French, german etc). can you please help me how would I implement pinning and unpinning functionality that is language independent.

Comment: I'm surprised you can do it at all. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/03/54760.aspx

Comment: Sorry i cant understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Microsoft actively discourage programmatic pin/unpin. It's meant to be done by the user manually.

Comment: How are enterprise IT departments supposed to manage this experience? For example, we have thousands of kiosk machines that login and we want to be able to programatically blacklist / whitelist / group tiles in scenarios where thare are no "users".

Comment: You can do this in PowerShell but I tried in C#, VB, but everytime I failed... Script PS : http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b66434f1-4b3f-4a94-8dc3-e406eb30b750
(to pin to Modern UI, you must add 51201 at $verbs )

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you shouldn't do this.

I don't have access to the operating system to confirm this, but you should find the strings in the registry or, perhaps to avoid making it that easy, they might only be in resources.

Answer (score 0):

It works, try this:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int LoadString(IntPtr hInstance, uint uID, StringBuilder lpBuffer, int nBufferMax);

    int MAX_PATH = 255;
    var actionIndex = pin ? 5386 : 5387; // 5386 is the DLL index for"Pin to Tas&kbar", ref. http://www.win7dll.info/shell32_dll.html
    StringBuilder szPinToStartLocalized = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    IntPtr hShell32 = LoadLibrary("Shell32.dll");
    LoadString(hShell32, (uint)actionIndex, szPinToStartLocalized, MAX_PATH);
    string localizedVerb = szPinToStartLocalized.ToString();

If (verbName.Equals(localizedVerb )) Or (verbName.Equals(localizedVerb )) Then
```